# Edit Android templates in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to edit default Android Studio templates but can't seem to find them. After looking for an answer for hours, I couldn't find anything that is remotely useful. Either everyone redirects to official docs (not useful, already been there and couldn't find an answer) or suggests something related to live templates.

So how can I change these horrible templates to something that is actually useful? Where are those stored nowadays?
[image]

Comment: I don't know that those have ever been officially editable. The storage details may vary by IDE version.

Comment: In older versions of AS you could override them, officially or not, as they were stored locally. Currently I think they're kept in sync by gradle somehow. But I am not sure, it's just what I've read around.

Comment: `So how can I change these horrible templates to something that is actually useful?`well, `horrible` is perhaps a strong word to use, i'm sure these are useful to some, they just aren't your preferred templates :) interesting question though, following to see what people say

Comment: @a_local_nobody when you're create something the first time, sure, they're useful but after that they just stop being useful. I need a template to create all the basic boilerplate code and extra files but no more than needed. Otherwise I just have to manually delete it every time. Before compose I'd use mostly Empty Activity or run a script but now even Empty Compose Activity does it wrong. Every time it recreates theme files and adds a `Greeting` function. That's just annoying. If I could add my own I'd simply ignore the existing ones but I don't think I can.